# Clerk fails to get the publishable key from the environment variables in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, netlify, clerk

I have a site I've built with Next 13 (experimental app directory) and have integrated authentication in my site with Clerk.

Everything works well on my local environment. When deployed to Netlify, it builds just fine, but if I try to visit the site it doesn't load, and in the console I see the following error:

```
@clerk/nextjs: Missing publishableKey. You can get your key at https://dashboard.clerk.com/last-active?path=api-keys.
    at Object.throwMissingPublishableKeyError
```

I do have my publishable key in my environment variables in Netlify under `NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY`. I've also placed it under `CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` just in case.

Also, does it supposed to get scoped automatically by some clerk code? Because in my code I don't really use that variable anywhere and don't see the documentation telling me I need to.

Comment: Same Issue with me Is anybody know how to fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and to fix it i just went to the file with the declaration of ClerkProvider and added the publishable key.

```js
function ContextProviders({ children, pageProps }) {
    return (
            <ClerkProvider {...pageProps} publishableKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
              {children}
            </ClerkProvider>

    )
}

export default ContextProviders
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should add clerk key and secret to your project secrets

`https://github.com/{username}/{project}/settings/secrets/actions`

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=********************
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=***************
```

2. in GitHub workflow you should load env vars required for the job

specifically when you do `yarn run build` add these variables with build step like this

```
      - run: yarn install && yarn run build
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: "${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}}"
          CLERK_SECRET_KEY: "${{secrets.CLERK_SECRET_KEY}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to the page where the ClerkProvider is declared and just add the publishable key in the  tag

export default function RootLayout( { children }: { children : React.ReactNode})
{
return (
<ClerkProvider publishableKey={'YOU PUBLISHABLE KEY'}>

<body className={`${inter.className} bg-dark-1`}>
{children}



)
}

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving .env.local to the root directory of the project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).